# How to change a image color with a color picker?

Tags: html

I have tried to change the color of a pic with a color picker but I haven't understood exactly how to do it yet.
this is the code I got so far:

```
<html> 
  
<head> 
</head> 
  
<body> 
        <img src="Other img/SPIRAL.png"  id="Img1"  />
    <div id="Img1" 
         onclick="changeColor()"> 
  </div> 
    <input name="MyColorPicker"
           type="color"
           id="MyColorPicker" /> 
    <script> 
        function changeColor() { 
            document.getElementById( 
              "Img1").style.color = 
                document.getElementById( 
              "MyColorPicker").value; 
        } 
    </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Why you put an `image` in `header`?

Comment: I thought that doesn't matter and that it just for the look.

Answer (score 0):

i use the function on the input and not on the div :

```js
function changeColor() { 

document.getElementById("img1").style.backgroundColor =  document.getElementById( 
              "MyColorPicker").value; 
         
        }
```

```html
    <div id="img1">I will change color</div> 
    <input name="MyColorPicker"
           type="color"
           id="MyColorPicker"  onchange="changeColor()" /> 
    <script> 
     
    </script>
```

without text:

```js
function changeColor() { 

document.getElementById("img1").style.backgroundColor =  document.getElementById( 
              "MyColorPicker").value; 
         
        }
```

```html
<div id="img1" style="height:100px"></div> 
    <input name="MyColorPicker"           type="color"
           id="MyColorPicker"  onchange="changeColor()" /> 
    <script> 
     
    </script>
```

Comment: it doesn't change the image color just the background of the text.
but thx anyway

Comment: No you wrong, try to inspect the div, you will see background-color is add to div. i add snippet without text.

Comment: I don't want to create a place that i can change its color only to change to the color of the image.

Comment: It's unclear, you choise the color and image change?